How do I get points of a spline to transform it into set of lines if I have list of Control points?
I am reading data about spline from DXF drawing. I have such parameters:

Control points list (coordinates)
Knots (each Knot is double number. Whats that?)
Degree of a curve.

I have read such articles on this subject:

https://habr.com/ru/articles/323442/ - general introduction on splines
https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/3526685 - some code about splines
article on Wikipedia

Now I need to get some points to transform spline into set of lines (and arcs, but lines  fine too). I have read on wiki that spline is a set of polynoms, it's like Lagrange's method but more adaptible. Is it possible to get coefficients of those polynommes?
